# Pygame detect collision between circle and square

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

For my pygame project, I want to detect collision between 2 square sprites.
However, one of the sprite is supposed to behave as a **square**, the other as a **circle**

`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` is supposed to check collision between 2 square, interpreted as square
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect

`pygame.sprite.collide_circle()` is supposed to check collision between 2 square, but interpreted as circle
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle

So in short, I want a mix with `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` and  `pygame.sprite.collide_circle()`. Is it possible ?

Comment: Do these sprites have appropriately shaped masks?

Comment: in order to save computer power, I have decided not to use mask, is it a good idea ?

Comment: Just as a note, even if it is a circle always have a bounding box(rectangle) which you check against first and if that collide check gets true, check the rectangle vs circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to mix the two, but I did make a collision detection that came the closest i could to what you want, here it is:

```
if circle_x < rect_x + circle_width and circle_x + rect_width > rect_x and circle_y < rect_y + circle_height and rect_height + circle_y > rect_y:
    #put whatever code you need here
```

This puts the circle into an imaginary box that is just large enough to go around the circle, then when the imaginary box collides with the rectangle the code you need to activate activates.

Comment: Thanks ! if only I had this 6 months ago, it could have saved me a lot of time

Comment: No problem,  I'm sorry that I could not have answered this sooner, I made my account a few weeks ago.